# Install Monogame on Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, monogame

I am trying to install **Monogame** on VS 2017 however the option on the installer for **VS 2017** is greyed out, even though I have **VS 2017** installed. I also have **VS 2015** and VS **2010** however I am not sure if it is those that are causing a problem. The version of **MonoGame** is *3.6.0.1625* and I currently have the directory: *C:\Users\MY NAME\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ProjectTemplates\Visual C#*

Please help thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem often happens when your templates are in the wrong directory.
The path you provided seems to be the right one tho.

Are your VS2015 templates in the C:\Users\MY NAME\Documents\ directory aswell ?
If not, try to move your VS2017 templates to the same directory as your VS2015 templates.

If those two are both in C:\Users\MY NAME\Documents\, look into Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ProjectTemplates and try to find the Visual C# folder. If it is missing add a new folder with this name and try again.

Comment: @Lenko Yes the VS2015 temps were in the same place as the VS2017 ones however I tried uninstalling VS2015 to see for any difference. It didn't have an impact though as when I run MonoGame Installer it still allows me to install for VS2015 (even though I no longer have it) and doesn't allow me to install VS2017. And yes I do have a Visual C# folder but it is empty.

Comment: This is incorrect. MonoGame puts the 2015 templates in the 2015 folder and the 2017 templates in the 2017 folder.
By simply copying the 2015 templates to 2017, you will get incorrect results.

Comment: Creating a Visual C# folder in Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Templates\ProjectTemplates fixed this for me

Comment: @Darkside, The templates are the same for all newer versions of Visual Studio.This was not the case for .SLN files before or around VS 2013?(not sure of the specific version) A conversion was required for the project. Now a project created in a newer version of VS can be opened in a previous version, assuming the .NET target framework version and architecture  is installed on the computer. Solution and project files from 2019, 2017 and 2015 are all directly compatible without conversion.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone have this problem and is trying to install on non Admin account then just copy over whole `Visual Studio 2017\Templates` structure from your `Documents` to Administrator's `Documents`. (or the account with admin right you use in UAC prompt to install)

That solved it for me :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, simple answer is, that until MonoGame 3.7 drops, you are going to need to download the latest MonoGame Development build from the download page.  This is fine as the dev build is still very stable and based off the current MASTER version of MonoGame from source.

[image: MonoGame Development Download]

I did a short Video on my "Darkside of MonoGame" channel a while back which walks you through everything you need to know to get up and running using VS017. (there is even a version there for VS2015 :D)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zphaylhOrm0

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue. Uninstalling MonoGame then Visual Studio, and reinstalling Visual Studio then MonoGame worked for me.